# Flutter iOS build failed by camera plugin

Tags: ios, flutter

I've following version for flutter app.

Xcode version : 11.3.1
Flutter: v1.12.13+hotfix.8
Target: 12.0
camera: ^0.5.7+3

```
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    /Users/praveenbhati/smartlist/smartlist/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:10:9: fatal error: module 'camera' not found
    @import camera;
     ~~~~~~~^~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    note: Using new build system
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 11 Pro Max.
```

I'm getting above error, anyone know the fix?